# How to can I share all of mysql rows in Node.js? (handlebars)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, handlebars.js

I used this commans for sharing the first row (jack).
***node:***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.set("view engine","hbs")
const mysql = require("mysql")
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "stack",
})

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    
    db.query("SELECT * FROM names", (err, result)=>{
    
        res.render("home", {name: result[0].name})
        
    })
    
})

app.listen("1999")
```

***and hbs file:***

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<b> {{name}} </b>
</body>
</html>
```

***but***
but this project only shares first row of mysql result (jack)...
how to can I share all of mysql results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each

```
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{  
    db.query("SELECT * FROM names", (err, result)=>{
        res.render("home", {names: result }) // pass all the results     
    });
});
```

**hbs file:**

loop over all names using `{{#each names }}`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  {{#each names }}
   <h3> {{ this.name }} </h3>
 {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```